# Can the QField Android App integrate with Dropbox (in order to open & edit/view a desktop Project)?

Tags: android, integration, mobile-gis, dropbox, qfield

I have a project that I work on in QGIS (desktop), for which my project file and shapefiles / layers are all saved in my 'Dropbox' folders.

I would like to be able to open, view and preferably edit the above project in QField on my Android phone when out and about.

I have the Project file and shapefiles / layers visible in my Dropbox App, but the QField App seems unable to integrate with / see my Dropbox folders from which to open up the project.

Perhaps this question should be directed at Developers, or self built... (which I can't do) any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

As long as the [project is portable](http://www.qfield.org/docs/project-management/index.html#portable-project) this should work. We have tested [btsync/resilio](https://www.resilio.com/platforms/desktop/) which is conceptually comparable to dropbox and did not experience any troubles.

In order to edit files they need to be at a location which is writable for the app. This is mostly the case unless on sdcard, which is also [documented on the same page](http://www.qfield.org/docs/project-management/index.html#external-sd-card).

Comment: make my day this tip!