# Using QField with Multi-User Access also Offline?

Tags: qgis, postgis, database, cloud-gis, qfield

I got 10-20 QGIS-Users which edit all one Project online and offline. Sometimes they do it at the same time. Until now we only used QGisDesktop with a PostGis Database stored in QGIS Cloud(50MB Version).

Now we want to introduce QFieldApp. I already tried collecting data and it was great. We could see the added data within seconds on our laptop and Smartphones.
But it worked only online!

**So my Question is: Is it anyhow possible to collect data offline with a postgis database in QField?** (Also with manaually synchronization)

I know the QField Team is working on this.
"Connection based on-/offline synchronization"
http://www.qfield.org/docs/development/index.html

**Does someone know how long it will take till this service is published ?**

The second Part of my Question is:
**Is it possible to move a Database from QGisCloud to an other cloudservice like for example OneDrive?
How do you do that?**

I have read this post: [Can the QField Android App integrate with Dropbox (in order to open & edit/view a desktop Project)?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/214928/can-the-qfield-android-app-integrate-with-dropbox-in-order-to-open-edit-view)

But it is not clear to me how to move or how to create a database on this Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only answer your first question, "Is it anyhow possible to collect data offline with a postgis database in QField? (Also with manaually synchronization)"

I created a sync package in QGIS and copied it on different tablets. 
the input data to edit is a postgis table, in mode "offline editing".
Each tablet updates some of the objects in the offline editing postgis table.
when I manually synchronise afterwards, this perfectly works :)

The concept (I read somewhere, but it sounds correct) of Qfield synchronisation is that every "action", done on the tablet, is stored in a logfile.
like: "delete object 101", "change in object 103 the attribute field X into Y","create new object 110", ...
when synchronising afterwards, QGIS reads the log file, and does the same action again...

I hope this helps you